# how to remove just the .php extension when passing GET values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

i want to change this url **example.com/search.php?key=abc** to **example.com/search?key=abc**
using htaccess, how ?
im using php MVC, parsing the url be a controller and method that i will call later.
My search.php file is in the root directory same as the htaccess file.

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Try this or  if u have any queries let me know.

Comment: i replaced my curently htaccess with that, its worked !  but, its mvc machine doesnt work. where should i do place that new htaccess file?

Comment: okay finally i got the answer, i put your codes above my codes. and its works ! Thanks a lot dude !!!